# transforming (key,value) data into csv format

Tags: algorithm, perl, optimization

Suppose we have a data file with the following format:

```
$ cat data.txt
  a:23 b:25 c:76 d:45
  a:21 b:24 c:25 
  a:20 d:52 e:75 f:75 g:52
  ...
  (many lines)
  ...
```

What would be the fastest possible way to transform this data into a csv format, assuming this file is too large to read into memory?

The output should contain a header which contains all possible "keys" in the file; if a particular key is missing on a certain line, then that key's value should be equal to zero on that line.  For instance:

```
$ cat csv.txt
//a,b,c,d,e,f,g
23,25,76,45,0,0,0
21,24,25,0,0,0,0
20,0,0,52,75,75,52
... 
(many lines)
...
```

Here's what I tried.  It works, but I feel like all the loops are slowing me down.  Is there a faster, optimized way to do this?  I used Perl, but I'd certainly be willing to switch to Python or something else.

```
# transform_test.pl 

# build set of all used keys.
my %usedKey;
open FILE, "data.txt";
while(<FILE>) {
        chomp $_;
        my @fields = split;
        foreach my $field (@fields) {
                my ($key,$value) = split(":",$field);
                $usedKey{$key} = 1;
        }
}
close FILE;

# build array of all used keys, but sorted.
my @sorted_keys = sort keys %usedKey;

# print header
my $header = "//";
foreach my $key (@sorted_keys) { $header .= "$key,"; }
chop $header;
print "$header\n";

# read through file again to transform the data;
open FILE, "data.txt";
while(<FILE>) {
        chomp $_;

        # build current line hash
        my @fields = split;
        my %currentData;
        foreach my $field (@fields) {
                my ($key,$value) = split(":",$field);
                $currentData{$key} = $value;
        }

        # build string by looping over all sorted keys.
        my $toPrint = "";
        foreach my $key (@sorted_keys) {
                $toPrint .= defined $currentData{$key} ? "$currentData{$key}," : "0,"; 
        }
        chop $toPrint;
        print "$toPrint\n";
}
```

Comment: can you make assumptions about the header content?

Comment: why tag with python?

Comment: I'd be open to a python solution, which might be more natural.  I'll remove the tag since I didn't actually write any python, though

Comment: @Sobrique no, suppose you know nothing about what will be contained in the header until you actually parse the the keys in `data.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this seems to do the trick, given your spec:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @header = qw ( a b c d e f g h i j ); 

print join ",", @header,"\n";
while ( <DATA> ) { 
    my %row = map { /(\w+):(\d+)/ } split;
    print join ",", map { $_ // 0 } @row{@header},"\n";

}

__DATA__
  a:23 b:25 c:76 d:45
  a:21 b:24 c:25 
  a:20 d:52 e:75 f:75 g:52
```

Output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,
23,25,76,45,0,0,0,0,0,0,
21,24,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
20,0,0,52,75,75,52,0,0,0,
```

Does rely on hard coded keys though. If you need dynamic keying, then... it depends a bit how big your file is, because you will NEED to process it twice.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use Data::Dumper;

my %usedKeys;
my @rows;

while (<DATA>) {
   my %row = map {/(\w+):(\d+)/} split;
   push @rows, \%row;
   $usedKeys{$_}++ for keys %row;
}

my @header = sort keys %usedKeys;
print join ",", @header, "\n";
foreach my $row (@rows) {
   print join ",", map { $_ // 0 } @{$row}{@header}, "\n";
}
__DATA__
  a:23 b:25 c:76 d:45
  a:21 b:24 c:25 
  a:20 d:52 e:75 f:75 g:52
```

This will slurp it into memory. But you could to two passes through the file first instead. (as you do) to build the 'seen keys'. That's mostly the same as what you have - you just need to `seek` back to the beginning on your file handle before starting the second pass.

Unfortunately, as you don't have any way to know what keys you'll be seeing, there's no option more efficient than a two-pass sweep through the file, and relying on the kernel caching.

E.g.:

```
while (<DATA>) {
   my %row = map {/(\w):(\d+)/} split;
   push @rows, \%row;
   $usedKeys{$_}++ for keys %row;
}
```

Comment: right, i'm totally resigned to the fact that we'll have to sweep through the file twice.  However, is there a more efficient way to build the "current line" hash or to build the string to print than what I tried above?

Comment: Added a final example of counting up the header fields. I don't honestly think there's much in it though, as your 'expensive' bit will be the file IO.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is too large to fit into memory then it requires two passes: the first to build a list of all the column names, and the second to convert each row to the corresponding CSV record. I would write it like this

This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, and writes the output to STDOUT which may be redirected on the command line

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Fcntl ':seek';

my ($file) = @ARGV;

open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};

my @heads;
{
    my %heads;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        for my $val ( /([^\s:]+):/g ) {
            push @heads, $val unless $heads{$val}++;
        }
    }
}

print join(',', @heads), "\n";

seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    my %values = /[^\s:]+/g;
    print join(',', map { $_ // 0 } @values{@heads}), "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
23,25,76,45,0,0,0
21,24,25,0,0,0,0
20,0,0,52,75,75,52
```